# Remove 0 character

Tags: shell

I have a text file that contains junk characters after some lines. As far as I know this is character `0` (not `'0'`) although I am not sure. When I open the file in vi one such line looks like this:

```
ESH6^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
```

I am only interested in the `"ESH6"` part of that line, I do not want the rest. If I do a `hexdump -C` that line looks like this (`hexdump -C foo.txt | head -n 2`, the `"49705"` is part of another line):

```
00000000  45 53 48 36 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |ESH6............|
00000010  00 00 00 00 0a 0a 34 39  37 30 35 0a 0a 0a 0a 45  |......49705....E|
```

How can I remove all instances of this character from the file?

Comment: Note that you can get `vi`-like output for visualizing control characters from the command line with `cat -et`; e.g., `head -c 3 </dev/zero | cat -et ` yields `^@^@^@`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`tr`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/tr.html) command:

```
tr -d '\0' < foo.txt > output
```

This deletes (`-d`) all null bytes (`'\0'`) from the standard input and writes everything else to standard output.  The `tr` command is a pure filter; it only reads standard input and only writes to standard output.